# Can variables be use as ansible filter parameters

Tags: variables, select, filter, parameters, ansible

I am creating a list of URLs (just strings really).
I want to select the one that contains the string in a ansible variable 'blog'.
Can't seem to code the select parameter correctly.
Is this possible?

```
    - name: get blog_urls
      shell:  
        cmd: wp site list --field=url
        chdir: "{{ blog_docroot }}"
      register: blog_urls

    - name: show blog value
      debug:
        msg: "{{ blog }}"

    - name: select the correct url
      set_fact:
        url: "{{ blog_urls.stdout_lines | select('contains', blog ) }}"
```

blog_url conatins:

```
        "http://jackson2.sjfc.edu/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/oit/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/aaforms/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/admissions/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/arts-sciences/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/pharmacy/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/grants/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/alumni/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/wson/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/education/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/images/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/oit-test/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/provost/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/registrar/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/faculty-committees/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/faculty-files/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/avdownload/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/mac/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/giddnfellowship/",
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/dnp-mentors/"
```

blog would contain 'aaforms' or 'oit-test' or 'provost'...

If I hard code the desired value of blog (see line below) it works:

```
    - name: select the correct url
      set_fact:
        url: "{{ blog_urls.stdout_lines | select('contains', 'aaforms' ) }}"
```

But of course I want to pass the second parameter of the 'select' filter as a ansible variable.

Comment: *blog would contain 'aaforms' or 'oit-test' or 'provost'* > This is unclear. Does `blog` contains `aaforms` or `oit-test` or `provost` or does it contains a complete string having the or in: `'aaforms' or 'oit-test' or 'provost'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example in question is an *almost* working one. The select `filter` will return an a list based on the match criteria.

For example, let's say `blog` variable is `aaforms`:

```yaml
  vars:
    blog: aaforms

  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        my_blogs: "{{ blog_urls.stdout_lines | select('contains', blog) | list }}"
    - debug:
        var: my_blogs
```

This gives the URLs matched by the `blog` variable (in this case one).

```
    "my_blogs": [
        "https://jackson2.sjfc.edu/aaforms/"
    ]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would never have seen that. 
In my program, I want a scalar result instead of a single element array, so I modified your solution just slightly and it worked:

      set_fact:
        blog_url: "{{ (blog_urls.stdout_lines | select('contains', blog) | list)[0] }}"